# Difference between "ins" and "ins.good()" when passed in a while loop condition

Tags: c++, fstream, filestream, ifstream, ofstream

Given the following code:

```
int main(){
    ifstream ins;
    ins.open("infile.txt");
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;
    while (ins) {
        ins >> x;
        cout << i;
        i++;
    }
    ins.close();
}
```

Assume **infile.txt** contains:

```
1 2 3
```

What's the difference between the current while loop condition, and if the while loop condition is "ins.good()" instead?

I assumed they were the same thing until I inputted it to my IDE, where the code outputted **0123** when I passed **ins**, and **012** when passing **ins.good()**.

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, but got nowhere.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Passing just `ins`, it will call [`operator bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). That eturns `true` if the stream has no errors and is ready for I/O operations. `good()` returns true if the most recent I/O operation on the stream completed successfully. If you have any doubt about specific functions, always check https://en.cppreference.com/w/.

Comment: Both `ins` and `ins.good()` in a loop condition is a bad erroneous practice.

Comment: When this fails `ins >> x;` the code isn't checking that it failed, and carries blithely on as if everything is still all ducky.

Comment: @273K I've heard that before but I've never heard an explanation as to why.

Comment: @MysticalUser: In my answer, I posted a link to a question which provides this explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `ins` will cause `ins.operator bool()` to be called, which is equivalent to `!ins.fail()`.

The difference between `ins.operator bool()` and `ins.good()` is the behavior when the `eofbit` is set. When the `eofbit` is set, but all other bits are clear, then `operator bool()` will return `true`, whereas `good()` will return `false`.

See the documentation of these two functions for further information:

[`std::basic_ios::operator bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)
[`std::basic_ios::good`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good)

[image]

Also, your loop is wrong:

```
while (ins) {
    ins >> x;
    cout << i;
    i++;
}
```

In your code above, you are checking the state of the input stream before attempting to perform the input. You should do it the other way around. You should check the state of the input stream after attempting to perform the input, in order to determine whether the input attempt was successful. This is especially important if you intend to use the result of the input attempt (which you do not do in your posted code). See this question for more information:

[Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/12149471)

For the reason stated above, you should change your loop to the following:

```
while ( ins >> x ) {
    cout << i;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in this expression

```
while (ins) {
```

there is used the operator

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

It returns the value of the expression `!fail()`. `fail` returns `true` if `failbit` or `badbit` is set in `rdstate()`. Pay attention to that `eofbit` is not checked.

On the other hand, the member function `good` returns `true` when `rdstate() == 0` and `false` otherwise that is in particular when `eofbit` is set,